# Use a method from application controller in a class that is located in lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I use a method that is located in application controller i.e.

```
def some_method(a, b)
```

I want to use it inside a class that I created in lib/my_class.
So I want in my_class to write:

```
some_method("blah", "foo")
```

Comment: There are ways to make it accesible, but you shouldn't need something defined in application_controller in a lib class. Actually, it should be the opposite. You should move that method to the class and use it from application controller.

Comment: Why do you need to call that method in the lib class?